# Android Studio 3.3 File > New > Android resource file

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio 3.3. But I couldn't find the option : res > New > Android resource file.
Can anyone help ? Seems like a problem with version 3.3

[image]

Comment: can you share a screen shot of what you see?

Comment: @Tal - image added

Comment: In the picture you don't press File. only right click on the project.

Comment: @Tal - same result

Comment: ok. and what you trying to do? add other files to your project?

Comment: if you press resource bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Expand your project structure and then right click on `res` folder,then hover over `new` option then you should see `Android resource file` option.

In short:

> app > res > new > Android resource file

Answer (score 1):

when you have downloaded the android studio 3.3 file new versions some errors are commonly seen by users . you should go back to the site of developers.in and check the file address of androis studio I have also downloaded 3.3 just 2 days back but mine is working fine .

Comment: Ok. I'll try downloading again and check. Thanks